# Read text file into object array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object, bufferedreader, readfile

Is there a way of reading a text file into an object array? I have managed to do this using an object array of strings - But I can't figure out how to do it with an object array of objects. i.e. A Hand object array of cards. Here is my code;

```
try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file_name);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(fr);
            //Create temporary arraylist to store hand
            ArrayList<Hand> tempHand = new ArrayList<>();
            Hand hand;

            int numLines = 0;
            String lineHand;
            while ((lineHand = buf.readLine()) != null){
            numLines++;
            //Initialise new empty hand object 
            hand = new Hand();
            //Add hand 
            hand.addHand(lineHand);
            //Add hand to temporary array
            tempHand.add(hand);

        }
            //display hands
            for (int i =0; i<tempHand.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(tempHand.get(i).getHand());
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

With the piece of code above I can see where iv'e gone wrong but I can't figure out how to fix it. I have tried to make lineHand type Hand instead of string but then I run into problems using buf.readline(). Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: What exactly you after? You want to get Hand object instead of String when reading file?

Comment: If you want a Hand object, then create an instance of Hand in the loop, set the value of String in one of the instance variables in Hand object and then set the hand object in the Array/ArrayList

Comment: Yes I want to get a Hand object from file, then put the Hand into an arraylist to be used later.

Comment: then you can go with serialization.

Answer (score 0):

A card is a pair of values: rank and suit.

```
public enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES }
public enum Rank {
  TWO("2"), THREE("3"),... JACK("J"), QUEEN("Q"), KING("K"), ACE("A");
  String rep;
  Rank( String rep ){
    this.rep = rep;
  }
  public getRep(){
   return rep;
  }    
} 

public class Card {
  private Rank rank;
  private Suit suit;
  public Card( Rank rank, Suit suit ){
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
  }
}
```

What a Hand is depends on the game, but a class containing a `Set<Card>` will do nicely for games played with a single deck.

And now: How to read a Card? And a Deck?

The representation of a card could be `"CLUBS 2"`, a sequence of characters on a text file. Use a scanner to get one token ("CLUBS", "2") after the other and convert the String values to the enum values. (There is something missing in `enum Rank`, which you'll have to add.) But it's straightforward for enum Suit.

As for a Hand: that's just a sequence of Card objects, to be read as above and added to the Hand object's `Set<Card>`.